# Add Discount to Braintree Rails Transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, braintree, discount

Is there any way to add discounts to braintree transaction. I know it is possible to do so on subscriptions, but i want to add it to a non recurring billing transaction. Here is what i have tried which works fine with `Braintree::Subcription.create`

```
result = gateway.transaction.sale(
      amount: amount,
      payment_method_token: token_generated,
      options: {
        submit_for_settlement: true
      },
      discounts: {
        add: [
            {
              inherited_from_id: "2rhw"
            }
          ]
        }
    )
```

This gives me the invalid key error for discounts and add. Is there a walkaround for this or adding a discount to single transaction is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Stack Overflow @Feroz Khan.

Have you tried with `discount_amount`.

```
result = gateway.transaction.sale(
           amount: amount,
           payment_method_token: token_generated,
           options: {
             submit_for_settlement: true
           },
           discount_amount: 50 # Amount you want to discount
         )
```

[Braintree Transaction Sale discount_amount](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/reference/request/transaction/sale#discount_amount)

Comment: Yes I have. discount_amount only adds the field as a part of the transaction record it does not actually apply the discount to the transaction